# Why does a radio stream not appear on a packet monitoring tool?

Tags: networking, streaming, wireshark, monitoring

I am currently trying to find the URL to the audio stream for a webradio that only provides a flash player, that I would like to use with MusicBee's radio player.

After using Wireshark to monitor my wifi network while streaming music through their website and mobile app and filtering the packet list, I can't manage to find any stream related to the website. That let me wondering: How is it possible for an applet to hide itself from the activity on a packet monitoring program?

Just in case someone is interested, here's the url to the radio: [Rouge FM](http://player.quebec.rougefm.ca/)

Am I just doing something wrong or is there some mechanism that I am not aware of?

Comment: Does your packet sniffer look at all ports, or just 80?

Comment: All ports, for UDP and TCP, are being captured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

- use ''http.request or http.response'' display filter in Wireshark
- Display the ''Hypertext Transfert Protocol'' and look for ''GET''
- then look for the url in the html source

I toook the tip from https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/13425/streaming-url and tested it, successfuly on RFI live and unsuccessfuly on radioFG (since RougeFM was down atm)