# find url of radio stream

Tags: streaming, wireshark

I'm trying to find the actual stream URL of an radio stream, specifically [this one](http://player.radio.com/listen/station/985-the-sports-hub).

There are a bunch of questions for this, but none of them have helped at all.  Some have said that I can use wireshark or firebug to do it, but I can't figure out how to read the packet capture in wireshark to get the actual URL.  Some have said you can inspect the source, but I haven't found anything in the source that looks like what I want.

Does anyone have a clear, step-by-step guide for how to get the URL of a radio stream?

Answer (score 0):

The source of the HTML page shows it's a Flash player connecting to "clip_id=4fhfathiv5ic", which means nothing to us. WinPCap/Wireshark digs up some more, showing the Flash player connects to rtmp://uc102.webvideocore.net/live/ (look for the "connect('live/')" command) and streams H.264 with HE-AAC.

Comment: so is the full url `rtmp://uc102.webvideocore.net/live?clip_id=4fhfathiv5ic`?  If I want to add the stream to connect via VLC or to record with streamwriter, is that the url i use?

Answer (score 0):

Like armpwnz said, you could use a program like Wireshark to inspect the network traffic to look for the URL. I suggest that you use the filter "http.response or http.request".

You may also want to check this post out : [Why does a radio stream not appear on a packet monitoring tool?](https://superuser.com/questions/894860/why-does-a-radio-stream-not-appear-on-a-packet-monitoring-tool)