# Find stream url of Flash or html radio stream

Tags: streaming, javascript, url, audio-streaming, internet-radio

can someone help me find the stream url of this radio station I checked the page source but i could not figure it out can someone help.

[radio station](http://tunein.com/radio/965-KOIT-s34474/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the pop-up player and open the page source.
Look for `audioHtml` and copy out the value, which is an URL.

As the URL is escaped, you'll have to replace all occurrences of `\/` with `/`. This will yield a valid URL to a playlist file.

If you follow the URL and download the file, then you should be able to open it in a player of your choice.

***Disclaimer:*** I have no idea how reliable the playlist or the contained URLs will be. This was not intended to be used this way.

Comment: it worked on vlc tyvm!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a program like Wireshark to inspect the network traffic to look for the URL. I suggest that you use the filter "http.response or http.request".

You may also want to check this post out : [Why does a radio stream not appear on a packet monitoring tool?](https://superuser.com/questions/894860/why-does-a-radio-stream-not-appear-on-a-packet-monitoring-tool)